# Castle Windsor registration by convention set custom lifestyle

Tags: c#-4.0, castle-windsor

With Castle Windsor is it possible to use Registration By Convention and set a Custom Life Style like
[Hybrid Life Styles](https://github.com/castleprojectcontrib/Castle.Windsor.Lifestyles) or do you have to Register each component?

Comment: Ok so I have figured out how to configure lifestyle for each component, however what if I wanted to centralize life style configuration to a Contribute Component, which I would set from the calling app

Answer (score 0):

```
container.Register(
   Classes.FromThisAssembly()
      .BasedOn<ISomething>()
      .Configure(c => c.LifestyleCustom<YourLifestyle>())
);
```

or if you're using Windsor 3.1 or never:

```
container.Register(
   Classes.FromThisAssembly()
      .BasedOn<ISomething>()
      .LifestyleCustom<YourLifestyle>()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Mauricio's Lifestyle extensions(the one you linked), this is working for me:

```
using Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle;

/// ...

container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
       .Where(Component.IsInSameNamespaceAs<MyNameSpace.SomeService>())
       .WithService.DefaultInterfaces().LifestyleScoped<HybridPerWebRequestPerThreadScopeAccessor>());
```